# Clementine keyboard shortcuts not working

Tags: 11.04, keyboard, clementine

Does anyone else encounter problem with Clementine's keyboard shortcuts not working ?

I have them assigned to 
[image]

but they do not work. Although for instance the shortcut to open preferences in Clementine `Ctrl+P` works.

Any ideas/solutions ?

Comment: version of clemetine you are using - installed from where?

Comment: version is 0.7 downloaded from this site : [link](http://www.clementine-player.org/downloads) version for Natty 64 bits

Comment: this is funny as I'm using the same keys-action! since maybe 2003/2004  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Met same problem in Ubuntu 11.10 with media buttons shortcuts. "Use Gnome's shortcut keys" didn't worked. 
So I just set to "Disabled" Gnome's shortcuts for those keys. This solved my problem.

Comment: Can you tell in details how did you disable gnome's shortcuts ?

Answer (score 3):

Disabling `Gnome's shortcut keys` only works, if the shortcuts you want to use are not define by the Gnome shortcut system, because clementine cannot fetch the shortcuts.

Therefore we have to deactivate the gnome shortcuts and go to `gnome-control-center keyboard` to the tab `Shortcuts`. There deactivate the shortcuts in `Sound and Media` which you like to control with Clementine. For instance I disable `Play (or play/pause)`, `Stop playback`, `Previous track` and `Next track`. You can deactivate a shortcut by clicking on it and the if there is written `New shortcut...` press `backspace`.

Then start `clementine`, go to `tools`, `preferences` to the tab `Global Shortcuts`. Uncheck the box `Use Gnome's shortcut keys`. And assigne the shortcuts you want to use to control clementine.

Comment: Perfect step-by-step description, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Open up `System Settings`, select `Keyboard`.  Go to the `Shortcuts` tab, click `Sound and Media` in the left column.  For `Play (or play/pause)`, click on `Audio Play` to change the hotkey.

I changed it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>AudioPlay</kbd> for example, anything un-useful just to be out of the way.

Now (as previously stated) in Clementine, go under `Tools -> Preferences -> Global Shortcuts` and uncheck `Use Gnome's shortcut keys`.  Then click on Play/Pause to set a new shortcut and press the <kbd>AudioPlay</kbd> key.