# Play, Pause, Next, Stop on keyboard - how to set which app use it?

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, clementine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clementine keyboard shortcuts not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59820/clementine-keyboard-shortcuts-not-working)

I have I keyboard with play, pause next back, stop on right of the numpad, but sometimes it does not goes to the right app.

I got my Clementine player open, a hit play (keyboard), and then banshee open from nowhere a play something.

I go in clementine settings and change to normal keyboard and it worked, but randomly or I don't know why it stop going to clementine, then I go in clementine's settings, change nothing only click "close" and the keyboard is back with clementine for a while.

Is clementine the problem or ubuntu not sending the key to the right app?

I use 11.10 (11.04 was ok but I was not using clementine so maybe its clementine)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use keytouch-editor

> KeyTouch Editor should be used to create configuration files for
>   KeyTouch, a program to configure extra function keys in multimedia
>   keyboards, in case your keyboard is not yet supported.